# Is the linear acceleration of a descending yo-yo scale invariant?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Imagine an ideal yo-yo hanging steady in the earth's gravity field. The yo-yo consists out of two infinitely close but separated cylinders which together have a mass $m$ (homogeneous distributed over the cylinders) and thickness $d$. Their radius is $R$. In between the cylinders, there is room for a massless rope with an infinitely small diameter that's winded around a cylindrical axis connecting the two cylinders. The radius of this connecting cylinder is $r$. Obviously, it has an infinitely small thickness, to fit between the two big cylinders.

We let the yo-yo go (no friction involved). What will be its linear downward acceleration? Will it be dependent on its mass? Will it be dependent on the size of the cylinders (keeping the ratio $\frac{R}{d}$ and $\frac{R}{r}$ fixed)? Will a heavy and huge (but small as compared to the Earth) yo-yo descend with the same acceleration as a light small one? Will a light and huge yo-yo descend with the same acceleration as a heavy small one? Are there non-mathematical ways to find out (apart from trying)? I can't imagine that the descending velocity is mass or size-dependent.

Comment: What you have is essentially an extreme case of non-slip rolling down an incline (a fully vertical incline, here). As with all such situations, there should be no direct dependency on mass for the acceleration. The radial distribution of the mass does matter (e.g. $r$ - the smaller $r$ is the smaller the torque relative to the moment of inertia, and the smaller the acceleration). The acceleration does not scale with the size of the yo-yo either.

Comment: @KristofferSjöö I know that two cylinders (with different radii) rolling down an inclined plane end up with the same linear velocity. Are you saying that a descending yo-yo is equivalent to a cylinder rolling down a plane with friction?

Comment: With enough friction to ensure no slipping, yes. It's easiest to see for $r = R$ but the general case only amounts to a different moment of inertia, really.

Comment: @KristofferSjöö So all yo-yo's end up with the same linear velocity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the acceleration doesn't depend on the size of the yo-yo ( so long as $\frac{R}{r}$ is fixed).

The loss in gravitational potential energy, falling through a height $h$, is $mgh$

The gain in the kinetic energy is

$0.5mv^2 +0.5I\omega^2$

where I is the moment of inertia = $0.5mR^2$ for a solid yo-yo.

The string is wound around the circle of radius $r$, so  $\omega = \frac{v}{r}$

combining these,  loss in potential energy = gain in kinetic energy, so

$gh = 0.5 ( v^2 + 0.5\frac{R^2v^2}{r^2})$

$$v^2 = \frac{2gh}{1+\frac{R^2}{2r^2}}$$

comparing to the equation of motion $v^2 = u^2 +2as$, with intial velocity $u = 0$
the downward acceleration is $$a=\frac{g}{1+\frac{R^2}{2r^2}}$$

The lowest downward acceleration would be for a large yo-yo with a small axis.

Comment: Very clear! And as I thought indeed.

Comment: Thankyou, yes the acceleration seems independent of the size of the yo-yo if R/r and R/d are constant - as you said.  Perhaps someone will show a way that bypasses the maths, would be interesting to see...